# Adding search functionality to gridview in android

Tags: android, android-gridview, custom-adapter

I have custom grid adapter which contains image and text(Custom Object),on top of Gridview I have added Edittext, I would like add search functionality  when ever user enter text in Edittext.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to listen for text changes on the EditText and then update the contents of your GridView ASAP.

```
    // Perform search
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            performSearch(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    });
```

After you have filtered your data somehow, just update the contents set on your custom Adapter

```
// Changes the data used inside your custom adapter
public void update(ArrayList<MyDataClass> filteredDataList){
    if(filteredDataList != null){
        adapterDataList = filteredDataList;
    }
}
```